# iPhone Web app cache control for sensitive data

Tags: iphone, caching, safari, mobile-safari

I am in the process of investigating whether it is possible to prevent mobile Safari from caching certain file. I went through a few posts about controlling caches in SO (e.g. [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831734/iphone-web-app-disable-cache), [HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528649/controlling-cache-of-web-files-that-should-be-cached-already)), and a few blog post. [This one](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/02/06/iphone-cacheability/) seems to implies that components are not cached unless either `Expires` or `Cache-Control` in the response header.

I wonder if anyone has tried any of those and whether any of those actually works and don't work? Also, how to test them?